# "overloaded function differs only by return type" error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a hang of the base classes and pure virtual functions.

Here are the classes and headers:

IUpdatble.h

```
class IUpdatable
{
public:
    virtual void Update(void) = 0;
};
```

InputHandler.h

```
#include "IUpdatable.h"

class InputHandler :
public IUpdatable
{
public:
   InputHandler();
   ~InputHandler();
   virtual void Update(void);
 };
```

InputHandler.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "InputHandler.h"


InputHandler::InputHandler()
{
}


InputHandler::~InputHandler()
{
}

InputHandler::Update()
{
}
```

The compiler gives me this error at the `InputHandler::Update(){}`

> error C2556: '`int InputHandler::Update(void)`' : overloaded function differs only by return type from '`void InputHandler::Update(void)`'

As far as I see both the pure virtual function is declared as `void` with no parameters and the overloaded function again is declared the same way.

Comment: missing `void` in definition

Comment: Wow, I can't believe MSVC carries C's implicit `int` through to C++. That's absurd. Clang gives: *error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations* and has an arrow pointing to `Update`.

Comment: but why is it putting int by default

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov It's a relic feature from C where if you didn't declare `main()` with a return type, the default return type was `int`. This is true for all other functions too, I don't know why VS has this for C++ though.

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov references added below

Comment: @chris Just tested it, and MSVC doesn't actually accept implicit int (thankfully) and produces an error ([C4430](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173696.aspx)) instead. It just uses implicit int for further diagnostic generation. g++ does the same thing sometimes. (For this code, for instance, it also prints out `prototype for ‘int InputHandler::Update()’ does not match any in class ‘InputHandler’` in addition to the `forbids declaration of ‘Update’ with no type` error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the C++ file (definition) you need to define the return type:

```
void InputHandler::Update()
^^^^
{
}
```